# Is there any way or function in R to find the derivatives of incomplete gamma function or is it possible to obtain its derivative manually?

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution

I am working with a probability distribution and I have to find the derivative of incomplete gamma function as
\begin{equation*}
  \Gamma(\frac{\theta}{\beta}x^{2},\theta) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\theta}{\beta}x^{2}}t^{\theta-1}\cdot e^{-t}dt
 \end{equation*}
How can I find the derivatives of above function with respect to $\theta$ and $\beta$ both??

Comment: Can anyone help me how to get the numerical values for the above derivatives in R?

Answer (score 2):

These are quite complicated, but Mathematica is up to the task:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta},\theta\right)
&=\frac{x^2\left(G_{2,3}^{3,0}\!\left(\theta\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta}\\\end{array}\right.\right)+\log(\theta)\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta},\theta\right)\right)}{\beta}-e^{-\theta}\,\theta^{\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta}-1}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta},\theta\right)
&=-\frac{\theta x^2\left(G_{2,3}^{3,0}\!\left(\theta\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta}\\\end{array}\right.\right)+\log(\theta)\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{\theta x^2}{\beta},\theta\right)\right)}{\beta^2}.
\end{align*}
Here the complicated $G$ function thingy is called the [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).
Not sure of how much use this is to you, but I've certainly seen worse.